# Why didn't Rami wear colored contact lenses in Bohemian Rhapsody?

Tags: production, props, bohemian-rhapsody

In the movie *Bohemian Rhapsody* actor Rami Malek is portraying Freddie Mercury, brilliantly, if I may add. Rami  and the crew put a lot of effort to make him look and act like Freddie. He had singing lessons, and piano lessons. He wore prosthetic teeth and had choreographers and movement specialists working with him.

All this work, and still they didn't bother altering Rami's eyes, that are blue, to brown. This feels very odd to me, especially that it is very simple to change eye color with lenses. I believe they could also alter the eye color digitally if Rami had some eye sensitivity issues.

The movie is great, don't get me wrong, it's just that this is something that stands out quite a lot, and I am curious about why they decided not to do anything about it?

Comment: This question seems to fit [the definition of a subjective question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) as you're effectively asking about something that you care about but the makers of the movie apparently did not. "Why didn't the film's makers do this thing I think they could've done?" most commonly acts as a guise for "Do you like my idea?" questions.

Comment: @Flater Not necessarily. The question may have been addressed by the movie makers. "The makers of the movie didn't care about it" is a valid answer (if it's true). Or maybe Rami can't stand wearing contact lenses / touching his eyeballs or something. There are a number of possible answers other than a discussion of the merits of GileBrt's idea.

Comment: @colmde: OP already accounted for Rami not being able to wear lenses. OP's question includes why they didn't digitally alter it.

Comment: The teeth were the most striking feature in Fred's face; the eyes not so much. I don't believe it would be a completely different movie if his eyes had the correct color.

Comment: @Flater My question is not "Why do you think this happened?". There is nothing subjective regarding this question, nor the answer should be subjective. I am asking for a concrete reason why the eye color wasn't altered. Also, the absence of an answer at this moment, does not imply that the makers of the movie didn't care about it.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find any reason given so far, but we can speculate.

There are lots of reasons why actors opt to not wear contact lenses when playing a character (either from real life or a book).

For example, it is well know that [Daniel Radcliff](http://mentalfloss.com/article/574906/harry-potter-eye-color-books-vs-movies) couldn't stay true to the Harry Potter books with his green eyes as he had a bad reaction to contact lenses. The producers ultimately thought he was still a great choice to play the character and it didn't really affect the story line too much.

Digitally altering the colour of the eyes throughout the movie would be expensive relative to the reward.

In all, I think the producers didn't 'miss a detail' but rather chose that it wasn't important enough to the plot to worry about. To be honest, if you asked me (BrE brought up on Queen) what Freddy looked like, it would be all about the teeth and yellow jacket, I couldn't tell you the colour of his eyes.

Answer (score -6):

I wondered the very same thing and the only thing l can come up with and this still doesn't make sense because with today's technology, you can do anything but, l think it was a mistake and someone didn't do their job and think of eye color until they were half done with the movie, that's all l can think of.

Comment: With so much attention to detail in this movie, I really doubt no one would've thought of his eye color.